# Inconsistent gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a very simple Keras model and I want to compute the gradient of the different layers using TensorFlow. 
I start by creating the computational graph in the first cell of a Jupyter notebook.
Here is the code of the computational graph:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Layer
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
input_tensor = Input(shape=(20,), name="input")
print(input_tensor.name)
hidden = Dense(100, activation='relu')(input_tensor)
out1 = Dense(10, activation='relu', name="out1")(hidden)
model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=[out1])
grad = []
for i in range(4):
   grad.append(tf.gradients(out1, model.trainable_weights[i]))
model.compile(loss={"out1": "mse"}, 
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001))

np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.random((3, 20)).astype(np.float32)
Y = np.random.random((3, 10)).astype(np.float32)
model.fit(x={'input' : X}, y={'out1' : Y}, batch_size=1, epochs=10)
```

Then each time I run the tf.gradients operator, I get a different gradient vector (the gradient changes). This result is not reasonable. Where is the problem in my code?

And here is the code for the created Session:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   out_grad = sess.run(grad, feed_dict={'input:0':X})
   print(out_grad)
```

Comment: How is that not reasonable? Variables are initialized to random values, so the gradient is bound to change every time. If you want to avoid at, you can do `tf.random.set_random_seed(<something>)` at the beginning of your code (before creating the model) and you should get the same initialization every time. Also, `tf.global_variables_initializer()` creates new operations in the graph, so it is better to call that only once and run the result when a session is created, instead of recreating the initialization operations with every new session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using `tf.keras.backend.get_session()`.
I think that the problem is that `tf.global_variables_initializer()` reinitialize the training weights each time it is called.
When I run this code multiple times, I get consistent results.

```
 sess = tf.keras.backend.get_session({'input:0':X})
 out_grad = sess.run(grad, feed_dict={'input:0':X})
```